# V-for iteration ruins the styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, slider

I have a slider which consists of products. 
Right now I'm getting a list of products from the server and populating that slider with the result returned from the server. For this I have the following

```
<div class="most_buy_slider container special_proposal">
                <div v-for="product in mostBoughtProducts">
                    <div>
                        <div class="goods_item">
                            <img :src="product.ProductPreviewImages[0]">
                            <div class="name">
                                {{product.Name}}
                                <span>{{product.Manufacturer}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">{{product.Price}} грн</div>
                            <div class="economy">економія складає 57% від роздрібної вартості</div>
                            <div class="to_cart">
                                <button type="button" class="btn but_blue">в кошик</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

But this result in the following:

[image]

however, when I render simple html without v-for it loads correctly.

```
<div class="most_buy_slider container bigger_width special_proposal">
            <div>
                <div v-for="index in 10" class="goods_item">
                    <img src="images/samples/whiskyjackdan.png">
                        <div class="name">
                            Вологі серветки Вологі серветки Вологі серветки Вологі серветки 
                            <span>Ruta Selecta Ruta SelectaRuta SelectaRuta Selecta</span> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="price">
                            45,55 грн
                        </div>
                        <div class="economy">
                            економія складає 57% від роздрібної вартості 
                        </div>
                            <div class="to_cart">
                                <button type="button" class="btn but_blue">в кошик</button>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="goods_item">
                    <img src="images/samples/ruta1.png">
                        <div class="name">
                            Вологі серветки 
                            <span>Ruta Selecta</span> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="price">
                            45,55 грн
                        </div>
                        <div class="economy">
                            економія складає 57% від роздрібної вартості 
                        </div>
                            <div class="to_cart">
                                <button type="button" class="btn but_blue">в кошик</button>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your CSS, but in first code snippet you included you use additional div for *v-for* directive, that can break your styles.

Try this code instead:

```
<div class="most_buy_slider container special_proposal">
  <div v-for="product in mostBoughtProducts">
    <div class="goods_item">
      <img :src="product.ProductPreviewImages[0]" />
      <div class="name">
        {{ product.Name }}
        <span>{{ product.Manufacturer }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="price">{{ product.Price }} грн</div>
      <div class="economy">економія складає 57% від роздрібної вартості</div>
      <div class="to_cart">
        <button type="button" class="btn but_blue">в кошик</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, xYundy. Somehow your solution solved the problem. But whenever I press F5, the problem comes back again. Pressing "Ctrl + F5"  solves the issue again. I got very confused

Comment: Can you post your code source on github or other place to check?

Comment: I can't upload to any server now as it is a commercial project. But we can organize an Anydesk session if you have some time

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem
I was using Slick slider to display items. While data is being loaded from the server, the slick slider already gets initialized with 0 item in it. And when items has been loaded from the server, vue.js inserts data into the slider, but the slider still assumes that it has 0 item.

So the solution is to reinitialize the slick slider when data loaded from the server. 
I called the following after the data load:

```
reInit() {
        $('.most_buy_slider').slick('unslick');
        $(".most_buy_slider").slick(this.sliderSettings())
    }

sliderSettings() {
        return {
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 1
        }
    }
```